# JSplitPane divider location changed after focus lost

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jsplitpane

I have two internal frames. One of the internal frame has a panel which contains a table in scroll pane and text area which are separated by a split pane with vertical split. I have set `setResizeWeight(0.8)` and `setOneTouchExpandable(true)` for the split pane. I am moving the split pane divider to up most or down most position and opening the second internal frame. Now, I switch back to the first internal frame; but the divider location is changed from where I had moved it.

I do not want the divider location to change. Does anybody know the reason and fix for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem